# C# XML Exception tags description missing?

Tags: c#, exception, documentation

I never seem to see the 'description' provided in Exception documentation tags. An example is below:

[image: No XML Description For Exceptions]

Notice that I see the thrown exception type, but not the description as to when it is thrown. Where can I see that description?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the class definition press F12 to display related assembly or code section. In the code documentation there is information about which exceptions are thrown in which cases.

Comment: Ah, so it's really only a case of going to see the actual docs themselves? Mh, that sucks, but thanks.

Comment: I wish intellisense provided a better way of displaying exception data; but thats the only way AFAIK:(